# Get type by type name TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types

Is there any way to get the Type by it's type name?

I have a class:

```
class Foo{}
```

I have another class:

```
class Bar(){
    constructor(){
      const typeName = "Foo"
      Type<any> type = Type.GetType(typeName) //like C#
    }
}
```

I want to get the type of `Foo` by it's name holding in a `string`

Comment: Types don't exist at runtime so it's not possible.

Comment: What do you intent to do with `Type<any> type` ?